# User has no userprofile when using recommended method

Tags: django-rest-auth

I am adding a field to the user by using the recommend method [here](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html).  #3 How can I update UserProfile assigned to User model?

When I attempt to save zip code on the /rest-auth/user/ url I get the exception "User has no userprofile."

model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # custom fields for user
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):
zip_code = serializers.CharField(source="userprofile.zip_code")

class Meta(UserDetailsSerializer.Meta):
    fields = UserDetailsSerializer.Meta.fields + ('zip_code',)

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('userprofile', {})
    zip_code = profile_data.get('zip_code')

    instance = super(UserSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

    # get and update user profile
    profile = instance.userprofile
    if profile_data and zip_code:
        profile.zip_code = zip_code
        profile.save()
    return instance
```

Thank in advance!